# Calculate the density function of $Y=\frac{1}{X}-X$ where $X\sim U[0,1]$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, transformation

I know that :
$$f_X(x)=\cases{1 & $x\in [0,1]$\\0 & $x\notin[0,1]$}$$
Then:
$$P(Y\leq y)=P(\frac{1}{X}-X\leq y)=P(X\leq\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{y^2+4}-y))$$ as $$\frac{1}{x}-x=y\rightarrow x\frac{1}{x}-xx=yx\rightarrow 1-x^2=yx\rightarrow 1-x^2-xy=0\rightarrow \cases{\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{y^2+4}-y)\\\frac{1}{2}(-\sqrt{y^2+4}-y)}  $$ I assumed positive root only(dont know if it is right assumption). So I am stuck from now on. Any suggestions.

Comment: The general idea is OK. Just need to be careful about the handling of inequalities.

Comment: I apologize for confusing you. I misread your question. I think you have the correct answer.

Comment: I got confused whether it is right.

Comment: I assumed positive root because $P(X\leq (positive))$

Comment: Then $f_Y(y)=f_X(\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{y^2+4}-y))\times (\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{y^2+4}-y))'$ right?

Comment: Actually, for every $y\geqslant0$, $$[Y\leqslant y]=\left[X\geqslant\tfrac12\left(\sqrt{y^2+4}-y\right)\right].$$

Comment: So for $y<0$ the density function would be 0?

Comment: Any suggestions how to proceed?

Comment: Of course the density is zero on $y<0$ since $Y>0$ almost surely. "Any suggestions how to proceed?" See my previous comment. (What is stopping you now?)

Comment: @Did Thanks for changes/additions on my answer below.

Comment: @MickA You are welcome. Your post makes for a nice answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @André and @Did, your inequality sign is the wrong way. We should have
$$F_Y(y)=
P(Y\leq y) = P\left(\dfrac{1}{X}-X \leq y \right) = P\left(X^2+yX-1 \geq 0 \right).
$$
You found the quadratic roots correctly. So the general solution to the quadratic inequality is $$X\leq \frac12\left(-y-\sqrt{y^2+4}\right)\quad\text{or}\quad X\geq\frac12 \left(-y+\sqrt{y^2+4}\right).$$ However, we must have $X\in (0,1)$ so we take the positive range only and we get, for any $y\gt 0$,
$$F_Y(y) = P\left(X\geq\frac12 \left(-y+\sqrt{y^2+4}\right)\right) = \dfrac{2+y-\sqrt{y^2+4}}{2}.$$
For $y\le0$, $F_Y(y)=0$. Differentiating $F_Y$ (and rearranging the result slightly) shows that the density $f_Y$ is $$f_Y(y) = \frac{\mathbf 1_{y>0}}{2}\left(1-\frac{y}{\sqrt{4+y^2}}\right) = \frac{\left(\sqrt{4+y^2}-y\right)\,\mathbf 1_{y>0}}{2\sqrt{4+y^2}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{4+y^2}+y}{\sqrt{4+y^2}+y} = \frac{2\,\mathbf 1_{y>0}}{4+y^2+y\sqrt{4+y^2}}.$$

Comment: Does it matter whether you include zero to $F_Y(y)=0$ or to $F_Y(y)$?

Comment: Dont get how you simplify $f_Y(y)$. I tried but I get something more complicated. Do not understand were $y^2$ term is coming from

Comment: Hi @Don . I've edited the answer to show how to get to the density function. I don't really get your other question. But to define the cdf over all of $\mathbb{R}$ is the proper way to do it, such as is done here, separately for $y\leq 0$ and for $y\gt 0$.

Comment: Thanks. My question was if I can write $y<0$ and $y\geq0$.

Comment: @Don Oh, right. Yes, that's fine because the expression for $F_Y(y)$ evaluated at $y=0$ equals 0.

Comment: Sorry for poorly worded question. I was looking for that. Thanks again